# kendo ui grid programatically hide and show the filterable row

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, grid

I have a kendo grid with filterable = true, mode=row.
I would like a way to have a button click, fire an event that will toggle hiding and showing the filter row.
Right now, I have it working by editing the innerHTML, but this is not what I want to do in the end, for several reasons.

1) I need to have a saved version of the filter row values before they are removed.

2) After they are removed and re-added they will not work
...
many other reasons, just bad practice and there has to be a better way.

A button that fires the event: toggleFilterClick:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="gridFilter">
     <button type="button" class="k-button" id="kendoFilterButton" data-click="toggleFilter"><span class="k-icon k-i-funnel"></span>Filter On/Off</button>                                                                                                  
</script>
```

The Javascript code:

```
//Gets the innerHTML values before they are removed
var filterRowValues = $(".k-filter-row")[0].innerHTML;

//fired when the button is clicked
var toggleFilterClick = $('#kendoFilterButton').on("click", function () {                                                                               
    if ($(".k-filter-row")[0].innerHTML == '')
    {
      $(".k-filter-row")[0].innerHTML = filterRowValues;
    }
    else
    {
      $(".k-filter-row")[0].innerHTML = '';
    }                                                                                                                               
});
```

Any thoughts suggestions would be appreciated/

Comment: what happen when there is already a value on the filter and you hide it? do you want the grid to be filtered or not? you can just hide it instead of remove it

Comment: I would just like to hide the actual filter row in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would just like to hide the actual filter row in the header

I'm not sure if i get the point but if you just want to hide it just simply remove everything except`$(".k-filter-row").show();` and `$(".k-filter-row").hide();`. I create an example where when i hide the filter, the filter condtion will removed, but when it showed again the grid will refiltered with the previous value used to filter

```
$("#toggle").kendoButton({
click:function(){
    if($(".k-filter-row").css("display") == "none"){
        $(".k-filter-row").show();

        //show again filter and execute previous filter condition
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({field:"ShipName",operator:"contains",value:vm.get("filterOptions.ShipName").toString()});
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({field:"OrderID",operator:"eq",value:vm.get("filterOptions.OrderID")});

    }else{

          //store the previous filter value
          //autocomplete
          vm.set("filterOptions.ShipName",$("input[data-role='autocomplete']").data("kendoAutoComplete").value());
          vm.set("filterOptions.OrderID",$("input[data-role='numerictextbox']").data("kendoNumericTextBox").value());

          //hide filter row
          $(".k-filter-row").show();

          //to reset filter of the grid when filterable hidden
          $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({});
    }
}
});
```

See the details in action

> [DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/OhUmE)

Comment: Jayesh/Machun (not sure which edits were made), Thank you so much this is perfect and beyond what I actually needed. I used a combination of the demo you provided along with Vanice's answer to get exactly what I wanted. The demo is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just hiding the row instead of removing it?

```
//fired when the button is clicked
var toggleFilterClick = $('#kendoFilterButton').on("click", function () {                             
    if ($(".k-filter-row").is(":visible")){
         $(".k-filter-row").hide();
    }
    else{
         $(".k-filter-row").show();
    }                                                                                                                               
});
```

Comment: Hey Vanice, this is exactly what I was looking for Thank you very much. I want to also share points with Jayesh/Machun, as his answer was above and beyond what I needed. Is there a way to do that?